# html forms with php to create MYSQL Database

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

i have been trying to make a html contact form which will trigger a php script and then save details collected to mysql database.
After these configutations has been done , i try to make a test, and  if fill the form and submit the file , the process.php page is just blank after the submit button is clicked, no response on the job execution and no errors , i tried to edit database password and re run the form , i got a password error , which means the problem is not with the database connection , here is the code , any help would be highly appreciated.

*Form.html:*

```
<body>
<form method="post" action="process.php" autocomplete="on" id="Customer form">
<!-- this is for the customer entry details (form1) -->
   <p><font size =5px><center> Customer Form </p></font></center>
Name : <input type="text" name="user_name" placeholder="Enter Client Name" size="25" /><br />
Azienda : <input type="text" name="user_azienda" placeholder="Enter Client Orgnization" size="25" />
PARTITA IVA : <input type="text" name="user_partitaiva" placeholder="Enter client Partita iva" class="field" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9\s]+" size="25"/><br />
Address : <input type="text" name="user_address" placeholder="Enter client address" size="25"/>
No Civico : <input type="number" name="user_no" placeholder="enter house number " size="25" maxlength="3">
CAP : <input type="number" name="user_cap" placeholder="enter cap " size="25" maxlength="5"> Province : <input type="text" name="user_province" placeholder="enter province" size="25"> Stato : <input type="text" name="user_stato" placeholder="enter country" size="25"><br />
Phone : <input type="user_phone" name="user_phone" placeholder="enter client phone" size="25" maxlength="10" >   Email : <input type="email" name="user_email" placeholder="Enter Your Email" size="25"/><br />

<!-- this is for the customer service details (form2) -->
<p><font size =5px><center> LISTA TRATTAMENTI ESQGUITI </p></font></center>

Data : <input type="date" name="user_data" data-date-inline-picker="false" data-date-open-on-focus="true" /><br/>
Trattamento :   <input type= "list" list ='trattamento' name="user_trattamento">
<datalist id="trattamento">
  <option value="Visio">
  <option value="Corpo">
  <option value="Mani">
<option value="altro">
</datalist><br/>
Altro: <textarea name="user_altro"></textarea> (if selection is 'altro')<br/>
Costa trattamento : <input type="number" name="user_costatrattamento" step="0.01" min="0" max="5000" placeholder="Enter cost" /><br/>
Acquisti : <input type="number" name="user_acquisiti" step="0.01" min="0" max="5000" placeholder="enter cost"/><br/>
Spesa acquisiti : <input type ="number" name="user_spesaacquisiti" step="0.01" min="0" max="5000" placeholder="enter cost" /><br />
Note : <textarea name="user_note"></textarea>enter additional notes<br />

<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
</body>
```

*process.php:*

```
<?php
//process.php
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {//Check it is coming from a form
  //mysql credentials
  $mysql_host = "localhost";
  $mysql_username = "dbusername"; //here my db details were inserted
  $mysql_password = "dbpass";
  $mysql_database = "dbname";
  //Open a new connection to the MySQL server
  $mysqli = new mysqli($mysql_host, $mysql_username, $mysql_password, $mysql_database);

  //Output any connection error
  if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
      die('Error : ('. $mysqli->connect_errno .') '. $mysqli->connect_error);
  }


//form1
    $u_name = filter_var($_POST["user_name"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING) ; //set PHP variables like this so we can use them anywhere in code below
   $u_azienda = filter_var($_POST["user_azienda"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
   $u_partitaiva = filter_var($_POST["user_partitaiva"],FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
    $u_address = filter_var($_POST["user_address"],FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $u_no = filter_var ($_POST["user_no"], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
    $u_cap = filter_var ($_POST["user_cap"], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
    $u_province = filter_var ($_POST["user_province"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $u_stato =filter_var ($_POST["user_stato"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $u_phone =filter_var ($_POST ["user_phone"] , FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
    $u_email =filter_var ( $_POST["user_email"], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);

  //form2
    $u_data = $_POST["user_data"];
    $u_trattamento =filter_var( $_POST["user_trattamento"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $u_Altro = filter_var($_POST["user_altro"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $u_Costatrattamento = filter_var($_POST["user_costatrattamento"], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT);
    $u_Acquisti = filter_var($_POST["user_acquisiti"], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT);
    $u_spesaacquisiti =filter_var( $_POST["user_spesaacquisiti"], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT);
    $u_note = filter_var($_POST["user_note"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

  //validation_FORM1
    if (empty($u_name)){
        die("Please enter your name");
    }
    if (empty($u_azienda)){
        die("Please enter company name");
    }
    if (empty($u_partitaiva)){
        die("Please enter Company partita iva");
    }
    if (empty($u_address)){
        die("Please enter Company address");
    }
    if (empty($u_no)){
        die("Please enter no civico");
    }
    if (empty($u_cap)){
        die("Please enter cap");
    }
    if (empty($u_province)){
        die("Please enter province");
    }
    if (empty($u_stato)){
        die("Please enter stato");
    }
    if (empty($u_phone)){
        die("Please enter contact number");
    }
    if (empty($u_email) || !filter_var($u_email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
        die("Please enter valid email address");
    }

  //validation_FORM2
    if (empty($u_data)){
        die("Please enter date");
    }
    if (empty($u_trattamento)){
        die("Please enter tipo di trattamento");
    }
    if (empty($u_Costatrattamento)){
        die("Please enter costa trattamento");
    }

    //print output text
    //Print "contact details for ". $u_name . " has been modified ";
    //print "Records has been updated to server";

    $statement = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO Customer_data (user_name, user_azienda, user_partitaiva, user_address, user_no, user_cap, user_province, user_stato, user_phone, user_email, user_trattamento, user_altro, user_costatrattamento, user_acquisiti, user_spesaacquisiti, user_note, user_data) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");

//prepare sql insert query
    //bind parameters for markers, where (s = string, i = integer, d = double,  b = blob)
 $statement->bind_param('ssisiississsfffsi', $u_name, $u_azienda, $u_partitaiva, $u_address, $u_no, $u_cap, $u_province, $u_stato, $u_phone, $u_email, $u_trattamento, $u_altro, $u_costatrattamento, $u_acquisiti, $u_spesaacquisiti, $u_note, $u_data);
 //bind values and execute insert query

    if($statement->execute()){
      Print "contact details for ". $u_name . " has been modified ";
    }else{
        print $mysqli->error; //show mysql error if any
    }

}
?>
```

**My table was already created in Phpmyadmin successfully but was not updated with data from the form.**

thanks in anticipation

Comment: Are there error logs you can check? Otherwise we are at a blind guess.

Comment: Does the data get populated in the database table?

Comment: @Tim , there are no error logs when i run the program , i also tried to find a 500 code error but none is shown....

Comment: @Nielsvh the database table is not populated, after hitting the submit button it just redirects to the process.php page and ends there , no error reports , no success reports

Comment: Where is Java in any of this?

Comment: @chrylis , there i wanted to write html .. i had posted already the question before i  could change it

Comment: Who are you talking to in your question? Could you please re-phrase your question to make any sense for user that dont have a background knowledge. ``thanks alot for the guideline`` - who are you thanking, what guidline?  ``i have followed the step`` - what steps? ``all seemed well until I reached the last part that has to do with binding the response to the table`` - what last part? what seemed well? and so on

Comment: `$mysqli->prepare` can fail as well - check the return value for that, and so can bind_param. Also make sure PHP error reporting is fully switched on (you can google how) to show up any problems. When it redirects to the process.php page, watch in your browser's network tab to see that it comes back as a 200 OK status and not something else. You can also see what is being sent to the server to ensure it's correct.

Comment: P.S. a general tip: "die" is not a good way to deal with validation errors - instead create a list of errors, and a "valid" true/false flag. Wait to test all values, then echo (not using die) all the errors to the client in one list. That way the user doesn't have to post back 20 times to correct all possible problems, instead they can see them all immediately. Your users will thank you.

Comment: thanks alot adyson , i actually dont know what went wrong , i later decided to remake the program, running a text section per section , and funny enough the program ran just perfectly , i will look into changing to the use of "echo" as you sugested , because once the form is submitted , and there is a line left out , the data is still saved to the table created .... however this is not a problem.. thanks one again pal

Comment: Because `die` stops the process, if you were to add a `print` call after the last if statement, does the process ever reach that point?

Comment: the basic error was that some of the variables in the bind statement was having capital characters when in the first part , they were initialised with small characters....  apart from this , other commands was successfully executed.. i only changed the die to echo just to avoid my visitors to go back in order to correct changes as suggested by Adyson